# Unexpected date when converting string to timestamp in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

The following example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Feb 4 1997 10:30:00',), ('Jan 14 2000 13:33:00',), ('Jan 13 2020 01:20:12',)], ['t'])
ts_format = "MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss"

df.select(df.t, 
          F.to_timestamp(df.t, ts_format),  
          F.date_format(F.current_timestamp(), ts_format))\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Outputs:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|t                   |to_timestamp(`t`, 'MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss')|date_format(current_timestamp(), MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss)|
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|Feb 4 1997 10:30:00 |1996-12-29 10:30:00                      |Jan 22 2020 14:38:28                                  |
|Jan 14 2000 13:33:00|1999-12-26 13:33:00                      |Jan 22 2020 14:38:28                                  |
|Jan 22 2020 14:29:12|2019-12-29 14:29:12                      |Jan 22 2020 14:38:28                                  |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Question:
The conversion from current_timestamp() to string works with the given format. Why the other way (String to Timestamp) doesn't?

Notes:
[pyspark 2.4.4 docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) point to [simpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) patterns

Comment: I kindly ask you to provide feedback if you downvote the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the year's format to lowercase fixed the issue

```
ts_format = "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```